# How can I include the selected element in delegated jQuery's .on()?

Tags: jquery, delegation, event-delegation

I'm using jQuery's `.on()` with a selector to delegate to a filtered set of descendants, like this:

```
selectedElement.on("click", "[data-click]", clickHandler);
```

In this case, binding the clickHandler function to a click event on any descendant that has a "data-click" attribute (with any value).

If `selectedElement` itself has a "data-click" attribute, it is not bound. I can't use the selected element's parent instead, because it contains other children that I don't want bound. This bind is occurring inside a function that receives `selectedElement` as an argument, so I have no advance knowledge of what kind of element it is or what selector I would use to select it. I would prefer not to have to bind the selected element separately.

Is there a way to include the selected element itself in the set which is filtered and bound by `.on`?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: Use the parent element, and modify your selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Joseph Silber said, you can't really do that. Here is what I would do in a similar situation:

```
selectedElement.on('click', function(ev) {
    // Alternatively, you could do $(this).is('[data-click]')
    if ( ev.target.hasAttribute('data-click') ) {
        clickHandler(ev);
    }
});
```

That way you can still use your `clickHandler` variable if that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind them separately, but if you insist, you can bind them to the parent and modify your selector to only include either the container itself, or one of its descendants:

```
var selector = '.container[data-click], .container [data-click]';

$('.parent').on('click', selector, clickHandler);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4tDL/

Comment: I don't know in advance what the selected element is going to be, so I'm not sure how to select it from its parent. Edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Then just use @kalley's solution.